# what is the recommended callback for canceling AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-lifecycle

i have an AsyncTask executed in onOptionsItemSelected(), where should i cancel this AsyncTask? in other words, in which life cycle callback it 
should be cancelled?

**code**:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    Log.w(TAG, SubTag.msg("onOptionsItemSelected"));

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_enable_bt:
            Log.d(TAG, SubTag.bullet("onOptionsItemSelected", "menu_enable_bt"));

            this.mATEnableBT = new ATEnableBT();
            this.mATEnableBT.execute();
            break;

        case R.id.menu_disable_bt:
            Log.d(TAG, SubTag.bullet("onOptionsItemSelected", "menu_disable_bt"));

            this.mATDisableBT = new ATDisableBT();
            this.mATDisableBT.execute();
            break;

        case R.id.menu_exit:
            Log.d(TAG,SubTag.bullet("onOptionsItemSelected", "menu_exit"));

            finish();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Simple answer: only "onPause()" is guaranteed to be called, at least for most API levels. More complicated but very useful answer: see this link to [another SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35086967/) Your solution depends on your situation :)

Comment: @0X0nosugar Correct me if I'm wrong. If onStop() is not called this means whole process goes down, so you don't need to care about shutting down your tasks. In other words onStop() is not guaranteed only on extreme situations followed by process termination.

Comment: Here people think that onStop() and onDestroy() are not called only when whole process goes down: https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2s2hqh/whats_the_point_of_ondestroy_if_we_can_never/

Comment: @nickes - I think I read somewhere that from a certain API level on (but which ??? did not find the right page in the documentation ) also "onStop()" was always called. Continuing the search ... :)

Comment: @nickes - Found it :) The docs for [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) say that **PRE Honeycomb** an activity is killable after "onPause()", so I think for Honeycomb and later this means that only after "onStop()" your activity may be killed (under normal circumstances, of course)

Comment: a good post on how to cancel an asynctask http://www.quicktips.in/correct-way-to-cancel-an-asynctask-in-android/

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what this AsyncTask is intended to do. You have to ask yourself several questions to decide.

1. Should my task be cancelled when activity is partially covered by another activity? If yes, then cancel it in onPause(). Usually it is good idea to stop any continuous CPU consuming activity here since on many phones this will be last lifecycle callback before the phone is locked.
2. Should my task be canceled when activity goes to the background, for example home button is pressed, or next activity is started? If yes, then cancel it in onStop(). It is good idea to stop medium duration tasks here and/or tasks that are not vital for your activity working correct. Like it is ok to cancel feed updates here.
3. For all other situations cancel it in onDestroy()

Your AsyncTask seems to be short running one, so it makes sense to cancel it on OnDestroy()

Comment: a good post on how to cancel an asynctask http://www.quicktips.in/correct-way-to-cancel-an-asynctask-in-android/