# RecylerView Adapter causing memory leak when using on Click interface

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, android-recyclerview

In my `RecyclerView.Adapter` I have defined this interface:

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}
```

The Fragment which contains the `RecyclerView` implements this interface.
After 4 or 5 orientation changes **LeakCanary** reports a memory leak:

[image]

My `Fragment` looks like this:

```
public class ImagesFragment extends Fragment implements ImageAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

    private static final String IMAGES_FRAGMENT_TAG = "ImagesFragment";
    private int SPAN_COUNT = 2;

    private String categoryName;
    private String categoryURL;
    private int ImageCount;

    protected RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    protected RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    protected static ImageAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Clicked:" + String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle args = getArguments();

        this.categoryName = args.getString("category");
        this.categoryURL = args.getString("URL");
        this.ImageCount = args.getInt("Count");

        setRetainInstance(true);
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.images_recycler_view, container, false);
        rootView.setTag(IMAGES_FRAGMENT_TAG);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imagesRecyclerView);

        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new CategoryItemDecoration(px, SPAN_COUNT, mCurrentLayoutType));

        mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), SPAN_COUNT);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(categoryURL, this.ImageCount, this);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putString(IMAGES_FRAGMENT_TAG, IMAGES_FRAGMENT_TAG);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        System.out.println("OnDestroyView");
        if (mRecyclerView != null) {
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(null);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        RefWatcher refWatcher = MyApplication.getRefWatcher(getActivity());
        refWatcher.watch(this);
    }
}
```

My `Adapter`:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ImagesViewHolder> {

    private static final String IMAGES_FRAGMENT_TAG = "ImagesFragment";
    private Context mContext;
    private static OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

    private Integer imageCount;

    public ImageAdapter(String url, Integer imageCount, OnItemClickListener itemListener) {
        this.ROOTURL = url;
        this.imageCount = imageCount;
        this.onItemClickListener = itemListener;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return imageCount;
    }

    @Override
    public ImagesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        this.mContext = parent.getContext();

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.images_viewitem, parent, false);
        ImagesViewHolder imagesViewHolder = new ImagesViewHolder(v);
        return imagesViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ImagesViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load("URL")
                .asBitmap()
                .centerCrop()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                .into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(holder.image) {
                    @Override
                    public void onLoadFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {
                        super.onLoadFailed(e, errorDrawable);
                        Log.e(IMAGES_FRAGMENT_TAG, "on load failed");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                        super.onResourceReady(bitmap, glideAnimation);
                        holder.image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    }
                });
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

    public static class ImagesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private static final int PALETTE_SIZE = 24;
        CardView cv;
        ImageView image;
        RelativeLayout mImageViewWrapper;

        ImagesViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagesCardView);
            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.images_ImageView);
            mImageViewWrapper = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Images_imageViewWrapper);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, this.getLayoutPosition());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't forget to accept  the answer which helped you solve your problem! This indicates to other people which answer contains the solution to your problem. You can accept an answer with the checkmark below the vote buttons.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is this line in your `Fragment`:

```
protected static ImageAdapter mAdapter;
```

And this line in your `Adapter`:

```
private static OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;
```

**NEVER** use `static` for variables. Just don't do it unless you really know what you are doing. The `static` keyword causes your `ImageAdapter` and `OnClickListener` to stick around after the `Fragment` is garbage collected. It means that the variable `mAdapter` is not part of any instance of your `Fragment` but instead part of the class itself - which of course is an instant memory leak! Remove those and you should be fine.

---

And by the way you could have figured this out by yourself fairly quickly. Look again at the LeakCanary output:

[image]

It says that the static variable `onItemClickListener` in the `ImageAdapter` leaks an `ImagesFragment` instance - or in other words exactly what I am telling you in this answer.

---

Also you should read [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35086967/how-can-an-asynctask-still-use-an-activity-if-the-user-has-already-navigated-awa/35087188#35087188) to learn more about memory leaks.