# Android fragment still has methods working after being removed from stack

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

In my android app I have Main Activity and the rest are fragments that are coming and going.

The behaviour that I don't understand is that when I bring a new fragment with some methods in there (refreshNotification):

```
public class MessageDetail extends Fragment {


   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
   ......  
   } 

   void refreshNotification() {
   .......
   }
}
```

use it and then remove it from stack by calling `remove()`:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out).remove(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("msgDetailTag")).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

... the fragment is gone BUT **it does not destroy the method** `void refreshNotification()`. Meaning that it still exists somewhere. It's like those methods become the part of MainActivity.java. I thought when fragment is removed, all the methods in fragment java file are removed as well.

How to destroy all fragment methods?

Thanks

Comment: Please explain what exactly the problem is. Nobody can help you if you don't tell us exactly what the problem is and show us the code you think is causing the problem.

Comment: Also this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35086967/2310866 This question is about `Activities` but it sounds like the same problem.

Comment: Made some updates. When i remove fragment I want to destroy it's .xml and .java file. But now it seems like only .xml (visual) file is gone.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. What do you mean the methods are not destroyed? I think you misunderstand how object oriented languages like Java work - just explain what exactly is happening that is not intended by you and then we can help you figure it out.

Comment: Ok. Let's say I have `MainActivity.java`. Then I have first fragment that includes: `Contacts.java` and `contacts.xml`. And then I have second fragment that has: `MessageDetail.java` and `messages.xml`. When I start `MainActivity` it brings `Contacts.java` and displays `contacts.xml`. When clicking on one of contacts it brings another fragment `MessagesDetail.java` and displays `messages.xml`. But then after going back to contacts I'm removing `MessageDetail.java` and `messages.xml`. But the method which was a part of `MessageDetail.java` still work when activating through Broadcast.

Comment: Well yeah, that's to be expected. The Fragment Object still exists it isn't just magically whisked away simply because you remove it from the layout. The Garbage Collector (The part of the runtime that is responsible for cleaning up and destroying objects that are not needed anymore) will only remove the Fragment when nothing is referencing it anymore.

Comment: You are saying you can still do something in the Fragment when sending a local broadcast. So in other words you are registering the Fragment to receive local broadcasts - which is basically just giving the LocaleBroadcastManager a reference to the Fragment which also means the GarbageCollector cannot collect the Fragment and destroy the Object. This is the real mistake here: You are not unregistering the Fragment from receiving local broadcasts - which of course means that the Fragment object sticks around regardless of if it is attached to the layout or not.

Comment: And just to correct your misconception: There is not difference between the the Java part and xml/layout part of a `Fragment`. Both are just two things you use to create one Fragment object.

Comment: And to give a name to the problem you are experiencing: It's called a memory leak. A memory leak is any error caused by objects being retained in memory when they shouldn't. They come up a lot when talking about actual memory issues, but they are all caused by one thing: That an object cannot be collected by the Garbage Collector because something still has a reference to it when it shouldn't. Memory leaks are among the most common and most severe issues and are the causes of many bugs. So you have to consciously watch out for them when you are programming.

Comment: Got it. I ended up doing unregistration`LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(receiver1)`  inside `onDestroy()` method. Thanks man. I finally got the solution from you :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144813/discussion-between-ekashking-and-xaver-kapeller).

Answer (score -1):

When you try to replace fragment it will go in pause state and it will not destroy, you need to remove fragment like this:

```
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG_FRAGMENT);
if(fragment != null)
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
```

or you can also get fragment by `findfragmentbyid(R.id.container)`

Comment: This does not destroy methods that were a part of Fragment.java that can still be reached through Local Broadcast

Comment: This answer is completely wrong. Detaching a Fragment from the layout will cause it to go through its full lifecycle. It won't just be paused or stopped or anything. Which transaction you perform has not influence on that. As long as it is detached from the layout - either with replace() or remove() or something else - it will go through its lifecycle all the way to onDestroy().